Why does PostgreSQL not add padding for column alignment at the end of tuple?
In the example here: https://www.percona.com/blog/postgresql-column-alignment-and-padding-how-to-improve-performance-with-smarter-table-design/

Why doesn't PostgreSQL add 2 bytes padding after the int2 in t2 to align the word correctly?

Why should PostgreSQL add padding bytes to the tuple? The next tuple will start at an address that is divisible by eight, and if there is unused space left between the tuples, it belongs to none of them. Increasing the size of a tuple for no good reason would be a bad thing to do.
